# Jboss 4.2.3 Application with huge number of anonymous Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

We maintain a legacy (jboss 4.2.3 , ejb 3 ,jsp, jdk 1.6.45 64b  ) application.

This application make heavy usage of database, and respond to

- User Http request
- Web service request
- Some CORBA connections
- Some external JSM call
- Some MDB internal process

Http connection pool is standard (tomcat 5.5 with 250 connections) , database pool connection is raised to 300 (instead of 60 standard).

The jboss service.xml (where default thread pool isdefined) is

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.util.threadpool.BasicThreadPool"name="jboss.system:service=ThreadPool">
  <attribute name="Name">JBoss System Threads</attribute>
  <attribute name="ThreadGroupName">System Threads</attribute>
  <attribute name="KeepAliveTime">60000</attribute>
  <attribute name="MaximumPoolSize">10</attribute>
  <attribute name="MaximumQueueSize">1000</attribute>
  <attribute name="BlockingMode">run</attribute>
```

One of our customer have some bad performance during part of the day.
There is a lot of threads generated without any relation with the users activities.

Normal activities threads count is 300/400 threads

- Sometimes it grows up to 4 k in seconds and decrease slowly in minutes
- Sometimes it can grows up to 25 k threads and takes hours to decrease and application become unresponsive (need a restart)

Thread dump show that all this threads are RUNNABLE , but there is no stack trace (other "normal" thread show usual stack trace).

All those threads are nammed "*Thread-xxxxxx*" and belong to the "*JBoss Pooled Threads*"

We are sure that those threads are not created by the application, but we cannot find what could be responsible for this threads generation.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !
The problem was related to the SQL SERVER Jdbc Driver, our code use a setQueryTimeout instruction on a Statement , there is a bug in the driver that cause it to create a thread for each query to manage the timeout.

see :
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/785983/jdbc-additional-thread-for-every-query-when-using-setquerytimeout
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/669427/property-to-create-timer-threads-per-statement-or-connection-in-jdbc-driver

Removing the setQueryTimeout instruction solve the problem.

HTH !